# Check CONSTRAINT Not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have to restrict to insert duplicate data in my table with condition

Here is SQL Server Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temptbl](
    [id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DSGN] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [RecordType] [varchar](1000) NULL
)
```

I want to put condition on RecordType, if RecordType is 'SA' Than check CONSTRAINT (means if DSGN = 0 and RecordType = 'SA' Exist than i don't want to insert that data.

if DSGN = 1 and RecordType = 'SA' Not Exist than i want to insert that data.

If RecordType is other than 'SA' than insert any data

For that i create constraint but it is not work

```
ALTER TABLE temptbl  WITH CHECK  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Stuff CHECK (([dbo].[chk_Ints]([DSGN],[RecordType])=(0)))
GO



ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[chk_Ints](@Int_1 int,@Int_2 varchar(20))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result INT

    BEGIN
        IF @Int_2 = 'SA'
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [temptbl] WHERE DSGN = @Int_1 AND RecordType = @Int_2)
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 0
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 1
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 0
        END
    END 
    RETURN @Result
END
```

But it is not working. please suggest me

Comment: yes SA rows to have unique DSGN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the function and the check constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_temptbl_SA ON temptbl (DSGN) WHERE RecordType='SA'
```

This is known as a [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc280372.aspx).

Your check constraint wasn't working as you thought it would because when a check constraint is evaluated for any particular row, that row is already visible within the table (within the context of that transaction) and so each row was effectively blocking its *own* insertion.

Comment: Thanks for right answer. but i have one doubt... can these work on existing table? i mean from now i have to prevent this. i have to keep old records as it is.

Comment: @Hiren Use With NOCheck for only new data. Here is the link provided.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use **With NOCheck** for only new data. Here is the link provided.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Valutah, This was answer to the question of Hiren's comment on 23 rd February. I could not put my comment at that time due to having less reputation. Hope, you understood why i put this to answer. Here I am repeating Hiren's Comment again "Thanks for right answer. but i have one doubt... can these work on existing table? i mean from now i have to prevent this. i have to keep old records as it is. –  Hiren gardhariya Feb 23 ".